# JSF - Richfaces, process submitted form data and then confirm to continue or cancel

Tags: jsf-2, dialog, richfaces, ajax4jsf, confirmation

I want to show a confirmation dialog to continiue or cancel a save operation when a form is submitted. I have a form with a save button which is calling an action methode to persist data in the form.
When save button is clicked, a file will be readed on serverside before the form data is persisted. Data from the file will be joined into form data and then te form data will be persisted. I need some values from the form to define which file will be readed.  There is no problem so far. When a FileNotFoundException throwed or the neccessary data from the file is not found, then i want to show a confirmation dialog to continiue or cancel save operation with caused message.

Does anybody have some examples or any ideas how to handle this? Do i need to use a4j? Thanks.
I am using Rifchfaces 3.3.3 and Seamframework 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first i have to correct my question title. It is **not** going on "processing **submitted** form data" but a **form data that will be submitted after some validation**.

Now the solution.

For example I have following in my form:

- some filelds
- an a4j:commandButton to reRender the fields and perform doSomeStuff() action
- an hidden h: or a4j:commandButton to submit the form.

1-  User clicks on 'fake' submit button which is an a4j:commandButtton,

2-  Ajax call updates fields in reRender attribute

3-  After that,method doSomeStuff() is performed with rerendered field values

4-  In the end Javascript will run to submit form or not.

Form:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{personHome.person.name}"/>
<h:inputText id="surname" value="#{personHome.person.surname}"/>    

<a:commandButton value="Save" reRender="name, surname" 
            action="#{personHome.doSomeStuff()}" 
            oncomplete="return checkMessage('#{personHome.success}')" 
            id="a4jSave"    />

<h:commandButton id="save" value="Save"
                    action="#{personHome.persist}"
style="visibility:hidden" /> 

</h:form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script  language="javascript">        

           function checkMessage(success) {
                 if(success =='false') 
                 {
                    return confirm('Do you want to submit this form?') ? submitForm() : false;
                 }   else {
                           submitForm ();
             }
             }

            function submitForm() {
                document.getElementById('myForm:save').click(); 
                return false;
            }               

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use a4j.

Try something like that (non tested, but follow the algorithm) :

```
<a4j:commandButton  onclick="if(messageHasToBeDisplayed){Richfaces.showModalPanel('modalId');}else{doSomeStuff();}"  />
...
<a4j:jsFunction name="doSomeStuff" action="#{controller.doSomeStuff}" reRender="..."/>
```

This shows you how to display a modal panel if necessary.
Without more code I can't help you more, but I think this should help you...

Comment: I think also a4j/ajax call should be used. To be clear... I need a fake save(submit) button to fire an ajax call which runs file I/O operation method using filled form data. When the file operation is successfully completed then i want to call a JavaScript on the current view to submit form automatically or to ask to submit or cancel the form submittion.

Comment: Can you explain what does your code mean? What happend when i click cmdButton? I think that checks first condition en than executes modalPanel or someStuff ... But i need first doSomeStuff, check condition then confirm to submit...