# How to check if RichFaces component rich:messages has messages in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I need to check if a rendered `rich:messages` component has any messages attached to it, from JavaScript.

I'm rerendering the `rich:messages` component via a `a4j:jsFunction` after executing an AJAX call, and I want to check in Javascript if it has any messages attached (this would mean that validation didn't passed).

The code of the a4j:jsFunction goes like this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="validateSomething" render="erroFinaliza"
        execute="@form" action="#{someMB.preview}">
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

For now, I'm calling it on a `h:commandButton` like this:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="validateSomething(); return false;" value="Do Something" />
```

I need a way of checking the result of the validation via JavaScript, and then really submit the form.

I checked [rich:messages docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages-richmessages) to see if there is a way of checking if it has any messages attached, but it doesn't have a Javascript API.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hacky solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407978/jsf-richfaces-process-submitted-form-data-and-then-confirm-to-continue-or-can).

I replace the `a4j:jsFunction` with an `a4j:commandButton` that only serves to the purpose of executing the validation.

Then on the `oncomplete` of this `a4j:commandButton`, I put a JS that checks if the validation passed and then "clicks" another invisible `h:commandButton` that submits the form for real, calling the real action.

So, it goes like this:

```
<h:form id="id_form">
    <rich:messages id="errors" />

    ...

    <script>
    function submitIfEmpty(noMessages){
        if (noMessages){
            document.getElementById('id_form:hiddenButton').click();
        }
    };
    </script>

    ...

    <a4j:commandButton value="Do Something" render="errors" execute="@form"
         oncomplete="submitIfEmpty(#{empty facesContext.maximumSeverity});" />
    <h:commandButton id="hiddenButton" action="#{someMB.doSomething}"
         value="Do Something (not visible)" style="visibility: hidden" />
</h:form>
```